# Lift plugins like in Grails

Tags: plugins, lift

is there an equivalent in Lift to Grails' plugins ? IMHO they save a lot of time in installation and the configuration often works right away. It's been really easy to integrate things like Melody - monitoring - Google Analytics, JCaptcha, PDF generation and WYSIWYG editors. In Grails performance has not been an issue but I'd really like more compile-time help which scala provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of Lift widgets as well as Lift modules for OpenID, Facebook, OAuth, etc.